# String.Format: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I'm trying to format a string, using an array of values:

```
Dim args(2) As Object
args(0) = "some text"
args(1) = "more text"
args(2) = "and other text"

Test(args)
```

The function Test is:

```
Function Test(ByVal args As Object)
    Dim MailContent as string = "Dear {0}, This is {1} and {2}."

    'tried both with and without converting arr to Array
    args = CType(args, Array)

    MailContent = String.Format(MailContent, args) 'this line throws the error: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

End Function
```

Comment: Is this any language in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `Object` as the type for `args`? You’re just throwing away all your type information.

```
Dim args As String() = {
    "some text",
    "more text",
    "and other text"
}

Test(args)
```

```
Sub Test(args As String())
    Dim mailTemplate As String = "Dear {0}, This is {1} and {2}."
    Dim mailContent As String = String.Format(mailTemplate, args)
End Sub
```

`String.Format` accepts a `ParamArray` of objects, so it’ll let you pass one (`args`; `CType(a, T)` is just an expression producing a value of type `T` and wouldn’t magically change the type of `args` even if you cast to the right type) and treat it as a single-element array.

You might need to use `String.Format(mailTemplate, DirectCast(args, Object()))`, too. I can’t check.

Comment: This looks like what I need. How would I reserve 3 spaces in the new string array without having to declare its values directly? I tried:
`Dim args(2) As String()`, `Dim args As String() = {,,}`, `Dim args As String(2) `, `Dim args As New String(2)`...none of these are correct

Comment: @Flo: `Dim args(2) As String`